# Word problem confusion

Tags: word-problem

The floor of a room measuring 5.94m by 3.60m is to be laid with tiles . Find the least number of identical square tiles required to cover the floor .

I do not have the measurements for the identical square tiles , so how do we solve this question ? Thanks in advance !!

Comment: What is the surface of the room and what is a surface of a tile ?

Answer (score 1):

Hint:  You have a given rectangle with a known area.  You need to find the largest square tile that will fill it.  You need an integer number of tiles along each side. That might make you think of greatest common divisor (of what?)

Answer (score 0):

For imagery, let the room be measured in meters so
$\quad 5.94 m\times 3.6 m \approx 20'\times 12'. \quad $
If we think in centimeters, we get
$\quad 594 cm \times 360 cm.\quad$
We find that
$\quad GCD(594,360)=18 \quad$
and dividing the sides by 18, we get
$ 33 \times 20=60$ tiles.